# Ejabberd limit User Registration privilege

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Hi does anyone have an idea on configuring eJabberd server to allow User Registration for admin accounts only?

This is done through inband registration XEP-0077. Using Smack API as XMPP interface for java.

I tried changing ejabberd.cfg file's

Access Control Lists:
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "myserver.somewhere.here"}.

Access Rule:
{access, register, [{allow, admin}, {deny, all}]}.

mod_register:
{mod_register, [{access, register}]}.

But it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same problem and solved it by adding

```
    access:
      - allow: admin
      - deny: all
```

to the `mod_register` section. `admin` is my ACL and is set up like this:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user: admin@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with ejabberd 14.07 and the new YAML syntax:

```
acl: 
  admin:
     user:
       - "me" : "my.server.tld"

access:
  register:
    admin: allow
    all: deny
```

and it works.

Comment: that's the same thing. 

try register a user using xmpp api. do this process:

1. connect to the server
2. register a user 

you can register a user without logging in using that access control.

i have a solution which im about to try now.

Comment: @SwiperNoswiping, I know it's a very old topic but did you find a solution? I have the very same doubt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966808/ejabberd-xmpp-server-how-to-allow-registrations-only-from-admin-account Thanks!